# Trouble with passing on variable length argument list

Tags: c++

I wanted to write a format + args style function to create a string and call a function in a framework to access its script listener window for output.

the function is as follows:

```
void ScriptPrint(wchar_t* format, ...) {
    wchar_t formatted[1024] = {L"\0"};
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format); 
    wsprintf(formatted, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    std::wstring ret = L"print \"";
    ret += formatted;
    ret += L"\"";

    ExecuteMAXScriptScript(ret.c_str());
}
```

And to the best of my understanding, it should work, however when I call the function like this:

```
ScriptPrint(L"this is an integer %i", 10);
```

the output I get in the listener window is "this is an integer 1223523" (the numbers change but are never right).

I checked it in the debugger and thats exactly what wsprintf outputs. I'm not sure whether I'm using wsprintf wrong or the va_list.. help?

headers used: Windows.h, cstdarg

also the final function only takes wchar_t* as input

Comment: the line wchar_t formatted[1024] = {L"\0"}; is a bit un-accurate , the type of the array is wchar_t , not wchar_t * , that's why wchar_t formatted[1024] = L"\0"; is totally valid. if you still want the array-like initialization , you should write  wchar_t formatted[1024] = {L'\0'};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `wvsprintf` with `va_list`, instead of `wsprintf`:

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, format); 
wvsprintf(formatted, format, args);
va_end(args);
```

With C++11, you may do instead (with `wsprintf`):

```
template <typename...Ts>
void ScriptPrint(const wchar_t* format, Ts&&...args) {
    wchar_t formatted[1024] = {0};
    wsprintf(formatted, format, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);

    std::wstring ret = L"print \"";
    ret += formatted;
    ret += L"\"";

    ExecuteMAXScriptScript(ret.c_str());
}
```